# Exploiting the id from the HTTP response after dispatching crudCreate action

Tags: react-admin

I am creating form in which I must post one input before the others.

I must get the id from that post before I post the rest of the Form.

I have successfully dispatched the create action.

```
const createPromise = Promise.resolve(
    this.props.crudCreate(
        this.props.reference,
        { description: this.state.addInputValue },
        this.getBasePath(),
        null,
    )
);
createPromise.then(res => console.log(res))
```

After dispatch, I can log via the promise the following:
[image]

However, I am, looking to get the response body after the post which would be my id as seen below.

[image]

I thought about adding the functions from `ReferenceInputController` in my component but it does not seem be a good practice.

What would be the best way to get the id from the HTTP response?

Comment: Are you trying to create another resource so that it can be selected from a `ReferenceInputController` inside another resource form?